# apex:component rendered using apex:dynamicComponent - how to call controller method?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-vf-component

bit of an odd one...

I have a VF page:

```
    <apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="myController" >
        <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myComponent}" />
    </apex:page>
```

This works fine, content from myComponent displays perfectly in the parent VF page.

Here's my component markup:

```
<apex:component controller="myComponentController" >
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Block" mode="edit" id="theBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" id="theButtons">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSave}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!doCancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

The problem is I am unable to call any methods inside myComponentController.cls. Here's what one of those methods looks like:

```
    public void doSave () {
        system.debug('Entered doSave!');
        // Do some stuff
    }
```

My debug statement never appears in the logs, nor do any method entry lines for doSave() (same with doCancel()).

Any ideas what might be the problem here? TIA

Update: when explicitly embedded, i.e:

```
<c:myComponent />
```

The method is called as expected & I see the debug output in my logs.

Comment: Can you add the code for `myComponent` property? Or the full code for `myController` and `myComponentController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but here's the code I just used in my sandbox trying to replicate your issue, and it actually worked as expected. Try it out, see if it will work on your end.

This should be pretty much 1:1 to what you were describing. If this works, you can start building upon it to see where it all goes wrong.

**MyDynamicComponentController.apxc**

```
public class MyDynamicComponentController {
    public void doSave () {
        system.debug('Entered doSave!');     
    }

    public void doCancel () {
        system.debug('Entered doCancel!');
    }
}
```

**MyDynamicComponent.vfc**

```
<apex:component controller="MyDynamicComponentController" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Block" mode="edit" id="theBlock">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" id="theButtons">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!doSave}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!doCancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

**MyController.apxc**

```
public class MyController {

    public Component.MyDynamicComponent getMyComponent() {
        Component.MyDynamicComponent myComp = new Component.MyDynamicComponent();
        return myComp;
    }
}
```

**MyDynamicPage.vfp**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="MyController" >
   <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myComponent}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @smukov, hope to get some time later today to look into it.

Comment: @DavinCasey Sure thing. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think the problem was how I declared the component inside the VF page controller. I had it defined inside a private list of wrapper objects, once defined as ApexPages.Component it seems to be working fine - thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I was not able to post full code here. Please find it in wordpress.

https://shravanboddulawordpress.wordpress.com/2016/09/26/refresh-vf-component/